# MySql - Order by date and then by time

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have a table with 2 'datetime' fields: 'eventDate' and 'eventHour'. I'm trying to order by 'eventDate' and then by 'eventHour'.

For each date I will have a list os events, so that's why I will to order by date and then by time.

thanks!!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm not sure whether there's any hidden meaning in your question but the standard way of doing this seems to fit:

```
... order by eventDate, eventHour
```

That gives you hours within dates, like:

```
Feb 15
    09:00
    12:00
    17:00
Feb 23
    22:00
    : :
```

If you actually have those two fields as *real* `datetime` fields, your schema is screwed up. You should have a `date` field for the date and a `time` or integral field for the hour.

You *could* combine both into a single `datetime` field but you should balance that against the inefficiencies of doing per-row functions in your `select` statements if you want to separate them. It's usually better to keep fields separate if your going to use them distinctly.

If you *do* have to use per-row functions, you can use:

```
date(datetime_column)
time(datetime_column)
```

to extract just the `date` and `time` components of a `datetime`.

Comment: Sounds like they only want the date from eventDate and the hour from eventHour though. If the hour of the eventDate wasn't the same for all results on that date then that would be ordered before the hour of the eventHour.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to list out data as latest eventdate first, if records of same date exists then 
data will be sorted by time ie latest time first,,

You can try as below

```
select * from my_table order by eventDate DESC, eventHour DESC
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not save both the `eventDate` and `eventHour` into the same field if they are both `DateTime` ?

To get what you want with the current scheme you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
  ORDER BY 
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM eventDate),
    EXTRACT(DAY FROM eventDate),
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM eventHour)
```

Comment: I added the "solution" to their schema, but they should *not* be doing this.

Comment: I think everyone's in agreement that the question & setup is rather odd.

Answer (score 3):

Does

```
select * from my_table order by eventDate, eventHour
```

not work?

Comment: Sounds like they only want the date from eventDate and the hour from eventHour though. If the hour of the eventDate wasn't the same for all results on that date then that would be ordered before the hour of the eventHour.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by as many as you need, just use a list.  It will order by the first value, then the second...etc.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM table
ORDER BY eventDate, eventHour
```

If you have two datetime fields then you can get just the date or just the hour using something like:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM table
  ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(eventDate, '%d'), DATE_FORMAT(eventHour, '%h')
```

Comment: Sounds like they only want the date from eventDate and the hour from eventHour though. If the hour of the eventDate wasn't the same for all results on that date then that would be ordered before the hour of the eventHour.

Answer (score 1):

Order it by the id in descending order.

`<?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC?>`

This should work

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way that worked for me, just convert date to numbers of days whith the function **to_days(date)** and time  to amount of seconds whith the function **TIME_TO_SEC(time)** 
, example:

```
SELECT 
    nv.destac,
    DATE_FORMAT(nv.date_nov , '%d-%m-%Y %T') as date_order, 
    TO_DAYS(nv.date_nov) as days,
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(nv.date_nov)) as seconds

FROM 
    newsviews nv
WHERE 
     nv.active
ORDER BY 
      nv.destac DESC,  days DESC, seconds DESC ;
```

Esta es la mejor forma que funcionó para mí, sólo convertir la fecha al número de días con la función **TO_DAYS (fecha)**  y el tiempo a la cantidad de segundos con la funcion **TIME_TO_SEC (tiempo)**

```
SELECT 
    nv.destacar,
    DATE_FORMAT(nv.fecha_nov , '%d-%m-%Y %T') as fecha_orden, 
    TO_DAYS(nv.fecha_nov) as dias,
    TIME_TO_SEC(TIME(nv.fecha_nov)) as segundos

FROM 
    novedades nv
WHERE 
     nv.activa
ORDER BY 
      nv.destacar DESC,  dias DESC, segundos DESC ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it is bad practice to save date and time in different fields.

Anyways, assuming you are saving date/time in the proper format.
(i.e: Date format is yyyy-mm-dd and Time is hh:ss)

You first need to concatenate the date and time to get a datetime value.
Technically speaking you can do a ORDER BY ON a Datetime field, but it is not good practice again.
In our case when we run a CONCAT, so this is converted to a string so the resultset will be wrong.
So you need to convert it to a UNIX TIMESTAMP to do a ordering.

Its good practice to run a UNIX_TIMESTAMP on a datetime field before a ORDER by clause.

You can use the following query.

SELECT column1,column2, **UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(`event_date`,' ',`event_time`)) as unixtimestamp**
from table_name
Order by unixtimestamp desc;

Note:(There is a space between event_date and event_time in the CONCAT function. It is not showing up correctly here.)

Comment: Re "it is bad practice to save date and time in different fields": as with much of life, it depends on context :-) For example, if you want to select all records between 10am and 3pm regardless of date, separate date and time fields will almost certainly give you more efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

why not to use a TIMESTAMP to join the both fields?

First, we need to convert the eventDate field to DATE, for this, we'll use the DATE() function:

```
SELECT DATE( eventDate );
```

After that, convert the eventHour to TIME, something like this:

```
SELECT TIME( eventHour );
```

The next step is to join this two functions into a TIMESTAMP function:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP( DATE( eventDate ), TIME( eventHour ) );
```

Yeah, but you don't need a SELECT, but an ORDER BY, so a complete example will be like this:

```
SELECT e.*, d.eventDate, t.eventHour
FROM event e
JOIN eventDate d
     ON e.id = d.id
JOIN eventTime t
     ON e.id = t.id
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP( DATE( d.eventDate ), TIME( t.eventHour ) );
```

I hope this can help you.